# SQL CHECK() how to check if input is numeric value?

Tags: sql, sqlite, check-constraints

Hey how can I check if the input has 5 numbers? I tried everything like isnumeric/LIKE '%[0-9]%' they all not working...

I tried the following but it doesn't work.. please help

```
CREATE TABLE Code ( PIN TEXT NOT NULL, CHECK(LENGTH(title) = 5), CHECK(title LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'));
```

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GLOB` operator:

```
CREATE TABLE Code ( 
  PIN TEXT NOT NULL,
  title TEXT,
  CHECK(title GLOB '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
);
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dedfd26837005f0dd686c08ea1644232).